# How to get every time messages from service to activity using runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth

I have been stuck with one problem. I need some people which check a part of my code and help me with problem and critize my code (I write code but I haven't people which can say this is wrong or something in this pattern)

Generally.

My service get message from bluetooth (HC-05) and I can see values in Log.d, in service.

A part code of my service which get message.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            Log.d(TAG,"ConnectedThread: Starting");

            bluetoothSocket=socket;
            InputStream tmpInput = null;
            OutputStream tmpOutput = null;
            try{
                tmpInput = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOutput = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                active=false;
            }
            inputStream=tmpInput;
            outputStream=tmpOutput;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while(active){
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    final String comingMsg = new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG,"InputStream: " + comingMsg);
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Message message = new Message();
                            message.obj = comingMsg;
                            message.what = 1; // I need it to prevent NullObjReference
                            Log.d(TAG,"Handler run(): " + message.obj);
                            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                        }
                    });
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Write: Error reading input." + e.getMessage());
                    active=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    ...some code is hidden because it is diploma thesis
}
```

The problem is get message every time from this service to another activity where all is happen.
I tried a lot of things (with Threads,Looper,runOnUiThread, handleMessage and callback), checked a lot of posts in stackoverflow and I tried to combine with my project but all time I had nullobjectreference (for that i tried to use msg.what to check) , black screen when tried to move to my home activity (it is main) and update my textView or typical crash app.

Now I want only to get message from service to textview. When everything starts working fine, I want to parse string (for example 3 first chars) and send message to one of six textviews.

A part of codes from onCreate before method runThread() is started:

```
Log.d(TAG,"Check intent - result");
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("result",0)==RESULT_OK){
            mDevice = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("bonded device");
            startConnection(mDevice,MY_UUID);
            Log.d(TAG,"Check is active service ");
            checkIfActive();;
        }

        Log.d(TAG,"Check intent - connect_to_paired");
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("connect_to_paired",0)==RESULT_OK){
            mDevice = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("bonded_paired_device");
            startConnection(mDevice,MY_UUID);
            Log.d(TAG,"Check is active service ");
            checkIfActive();

        }

public void checkIfActive(){
        Log.d(TAG,"CheckIfActive: Started");
        while(myBluetoothService.active!=true) {
            Log.d(TAG,"CheckIfActive() active is "+ myBluetoothService.active);
            if (myBluetoothService.active) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CheckIfActive: Running method runOnUiThread - myBluetoothService.active is "+myBluetoothService.active);
                runThread();
            }
        }
    }
```

Method runThread() which should work everytime after connected with bluetooth device:

```
public void runThread(){
        //I used there Thread but when connection was fail,
        // method created multiply threads when I tried to connect next time
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
                 @Override
                 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                     while (true) {
                         switch (msg.what) {
                             //when is one, service has messages to send
                             case 1:
                                 String message = myBluetoothService.mHandler.obtainMessage().toString();
                                 rearLeft.setText(message);
                                 break;
                             default:
                                 super.handleMessage(msg);
                         }
                     }
                 }
               };
            }
        });

    }
```

UPDATE:

Is it good idea ? Maybe I can put JSON Object to service to send message and in the HomeActivity, I can try get values from JSON. Is it fast ? I send a lot of data, because bluetooth receive data of distance from 4 ultrasound sensors in 4 times in lasts until few milliseconds, everytime.

Here is screen how sees my data in service when I have debug logs.

[image]

Next idea, but still nothing:

HomeActivity (my main)

```
public void runThread(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Looper.prepare();
                new Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        rearLeft.setText(msg.obj.toString()); 

                    }
                };
                //Looper.loop();
                    //Log.d(TAG, myBluetoothService.mHandler.getLooper().toString());
                    //rearLeft.setText(myBluetoothService.mHandler.getLooper().toString());

            }
        });

    }
```

Service which should send data from bluetooth to UI Thread is the same (Check first code).

Screen from HomeActivity where you can see 6 text views. Now I want put all text to one view which will be refresh by get next message.

[image]

Comment: You should use a broadcastreceiver to let an activity receive messages from a service.

Comment: @blackapps Have you something examples. Currently I use 4 BroadcastReceiver to another things, but I don't see in my mind this idea.
How using "BroadcastReceiver getMsgReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){ 
on Receive(...){} }" can I get this message. I need some method all the time to get it (message).  (I know about actions in broadcasts).

Comment: @Bartusiak So what is your problem right now? You cannot receive data from your activity? You can receive data from your activity but it's null? or you can receive data from your activity but when display on TextView, it crashes the app?

Comment: @Nhãt_Giang I cannot receive data when I am in activity. I am working like test and error method. One time, i had null. Second time when I tried do something was nothing, but service worked. Third time app crashed - one reason null object reference, second reason cannot use loper when another is working.

Comment: @NhấtGiang For example: When I change code in method runThread() and put this: https://pastebin.com/raw/65201T9J , I am connected with HC-05. Service is working (I see message in Log.D), but I have black screen on the phone when phone is trying to show HomeActivity layout.
I know about while - probably it is problem with black screen, but every time need idea to solve my problem. Get message every time.

Comment: @Bartusiak you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger to send data/message from your service to activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this post a bit help me to solve problem:
[Sending a simple message from Service to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629071/sending-a-simple-message-from-service-to-activity?fbclid=IwAR0nmBQ_SJCVqkCRO3_jxtoILFU8Ww9EXVx9sCVct169sLM-VxrWtPdAOHA)

Maybe this link could help another people.
Thanks for help, now understand why i should use broadcast receiver to do this.